# Angular 2 - how do I make my index.html files title and meta tags for keywords and description dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, single-page-application

Angular 2 - how do I make my index.html files title and meta tags for keywords and description dynamic.

I'm using typescript with angular 2.

**Example of my tags:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>title needs to be dynamic</title>
    <base href="/"></base>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="fragment" content="!"/>
    <meta name="description" content="description needs to be dynamic"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords needs to be dynamic" />
```

**This is my route:**

```
{ path: '/', component: Home, as: 'Home', data:{title: 'Welcome Home'}},
```

**I've tried this but it didnt work:**

```
 <title>{{title}}</title>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a [Title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html) service. Otherwise you're currently on your own. You can use pure JS functionality `querySelector()...`
There are plans to support more tags in the `<head>`.
I'm not too deep into SEO but I think it would be better to use a server side solution for meta tags. I doubt search engines pick up meta tags that are added after the initial page load.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wnLWAW?p=preview) (doesn't update the window title because the app runs in an iframe but using the browsers inspect tool shows it in the `<head><title>....</title></head>`)

Comment: I agree.  I'm not aware of a use case where what you are asking for make sense.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do this because the angular 2 documentation doesnt have one

Comment: `constructor(private title:Title) {} ... doSomething() { this.title.setTitle('new title');}`

Comment: which import is Title from?

Comment: `angular2/platform/browser`

Comment: I get this error when I import it from there: "No provider for Title! (Home -> Title)"

Comment: Ok, I assumed it's provided by default. Just add it to the providers list in `bootstrap()` or your root components `providers: [Title]`. Don't add it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [@ngx-meta/core](https://github.com/ngx-meta/core) plugin, which might help you to make page titles and meta tags dynamically (on the route config and class constructor level).

Please refer the repository for instructions.

Comment: Can u add an example of how this works with the index.html

Comment: You can basically empty the contents of <title> tag on your html file. For the meta tags, it's even possible to remove them all, and let the plugin fill for you.

Comment: For routes, all you need is to add the metadata properties during the route definition, inside the "data" attribute of each of the routes. You can find detailed documentationat the repository page [ng-metadata](https://github.com/fulls1z3/ng2-metadata). The readme file will guide you with simple instructions.